# Find string value in ArrayList with own class

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

this is my first question. Im a studying business administration and started to learn java just for fun. I'm doing the MOOC course from a finnish university. I am at exercise 101. I have to program a library with a search function for books. One can either search by title, publisher or year.

My only ideas were those (that did not work):

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByPublisher(String publisher){
      ArrayList<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
         if (bibo.contains(publisher)){
         found.add(bibo.get(bibo.indexOf(publisher)));              
            }            
         return found;
```

or:

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByTitle(String title){
         ArrayList<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
         String [] neueListe = new String[bibo.size()];
         for (int i = 0; i < bibo.size(); i++){
             neueListe[i] = bibo.get(i).toString();
             found.add(neueListe[i].toString());
         }
         return found;
```

`"bibo"` is the `ArrayList` with the books.

I've searched the internet for ideas and solutions and of course came across several on GitHub. But every code I found used the same idea:

```
for(Book i : this.bibo){
        if(StringUtils.included(i.title(), title)){
            found.add(i);
        }
```

In the course there was never used the `StringUtils.included` and my NetBeans version doesn't know it.

Where the heck is my error in reasoning?

Thanks a lot already in the first place :-)

Comment: `StringUtils` belongs to Apache Commons, a third-party library that you must include in the project if you want to use it. As you do this for learning, you should better code your own `StringUtils.included` method.

Answer (score 1):

The `StringUtils` is a third part library form `Apache Commons Lang`. if you want to use this class you should add the `Apache Commons Lang` to your project in the Netbeans.
This tutorial shows how to add Apache Commons in Netbeans:
https://www.satollo.net/netbeans-apache-commons-and-commons-javadoc-for-auto-completion

Answer (score 0):

The problem in

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByPublisher(String publisher){
      ArrayList<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
         if (bibo.contains(publisher)){
             found.add(bibo.get(bibo.indexOf(publisher)));              
         }            
         return found;
```

is that you are asking if `bibo` contains a `String` while you should ask if it contains a book which publisher field equals to that String (the input to searchByPubisher).

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByPublisher(String publisher){
      ArrayList<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
       for(Book b: bibo){
        if(b.getPublisher().equals(publisher))
         found.add(b);              
         }            
         return found;
}
```

The `searchByTitle` function can be implemented similarly.

I would also mention that you can also use `Streams` to do the job.
(Since you are learning `java`) something like the following should be enough to let you make it work by yourself:

```
List<Book> found = 
    bibo.stream()
                .filter(b -> t.getPublisher().equals(publisher))
                .collect(toList());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByTitle(String title){
     ArrayList<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
     for (Book book: bibo) {
         if(book.title.contains(title)) {
              found.add(book);
         }
     }
     return found;
```

You could also look at the Java 8 Streams and the filter functions when you have more java experience. [Java 8 Streams example](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils is a class from the org.apache.commons.lang library

1. Download the latest binary .zip file from the apache link (currently commons-lang3-3.5-bin.zip):
   https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi
2. Create a "lib" folder in your NetBeans directory
   [image]
3. Copy only the .jar file of the zip folder and past it into the lib directory that you created
4. Open NetBeans, Right Click on your Project > Proprieties > Libraries > Add JAR/Folder
5. Select "Relative Path" and select the jar file that you pasted into your library folder